# pyodbc connection string sql server authentication

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I know this question has been asked many times on the web resulting in many different solutions none which have worked for me.

For my scenario I'm attempting to do a simple connection to a MS Sql database connecting just with Service account username and password using windows authentication isn't an option for my task.

This is the connection string that I am providing:

```
databaseConnection = 'DRIVER={SQL Server}; SERVER=ServerName; Database=DatbaseName; UID=UserId; PWD=password;'
```

This is the error I receive when trying to run the script:

```
    dbConnection = pyodbc.connect(DATABASE.databaseConnection)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
[SQL Server]Cannot open database "XXXX" requested by the login. The login failed.
(4060) (SQLDriverConnect); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
[SQL Server]Cannot open database "XXXX" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060)')
```

Is there anything incorrect about this connection string? I have double checked the username and password by copy and pasting it into SQL Server Management Studio and logging into the database from there and it is successful.

Comment: Did you try User Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword; ?

Comment: @YevgenYampolskiy Changing the attributes to User Id and Password doesn't work. Receive an error for invalid attributes

Comment: Are you attempting to connect using a Windows Service?

Comment: @þăדᴚῖↄқ I have resolved this thanks

Comment: Want to share your resolution? I came across this question while trying to solve a similar problem.

Comment: @þăדᴚῖↄқ in my case it ended up being an issue on the database administrators end. My application was dependent on two databases and he only provided me access to one of the databases. The issue was hidden from me because the error message was stating it could not open the database I had access to when it should have stated the other database. I'm assuming database 1 was shown in the error msg because that is the database used in the connection string. I accessed database 2 later on in a join query of the two databases.

Comment: @þăדᴚῖↄқ when you asked if i were using a "Windows Service" are you asking if I'm using a Windows driver to connect to the database? want to give me a bit of background on your issue i'll see if i can help you.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem myself and I fixed it by going to the Microsoft SQL Server management studio and manually connecting the database to the user account you login into the database with.

To do this:

- Open Microsoft SQL Server management studio and connect to your server.
- Go to login, right click on the correct user, and go to properties.
- On the top left there's a panel (titled "select a page"). Go to User mapping.
- On the table displayed, where it says user (second column), type in the name of the user next to the database you are using.

While you are at it, look at the panel at the bottom. Where it says `Database role membership for:{database name}`, make sure you have `db_datareader`  and `db_datawriter` checked.

Comment: What do you mean by 'go to login'? I'm in SSMS, have connected to my server, but I can't see where I would login?

Comment: Expand the database in Object Explorer, then go Security -> Logins.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to have a connection string using sqlalchemy (see https://www.sqlalchemy.org/):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from db import Db

#Get localhost DB
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://myDbUser:myDbPassword@localhost:1433/MyDatabase?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=no')

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = DBSession()
db = Db(session)
print "the widget number is: "+db.widgetNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and the problem was the database name.

I was putting the database name between brackets, like [DB_NAME], however as soon as I removed the brackets to DB_NAME it worked fine.

Please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the MSSQL server in the obdc datasources and give the name with the pyodbc connection as below.My userdsn name is MyConnection

```
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=MyConnection')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP (1000) [DepartmentID]      ,[Name]      ,[GroupName]      ,[ModifiedDate]  FROM ["
               "AdventureWorks2019].[HumanResources].[Department]")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row.DepartmentID, row.Name)
```

It is working for me. Let me know if there are any other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The important parameter is where the “username and password” were set, I am replacing it with “Trusted_Connection=yes” so the user account logged into Windows is used instead.

```
import pyodbc

conn_str = ("Driver={SQL Server};"
                           "Server=<server-name>;"
                            "Database=<db-name>;"
                            "Trusted_Connection=yes")

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

cursor = conn.cursor()
```